# Display CSV content as url links and pictures in website in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, image, csv, hyperlink

I have a CSV file with a lot of links, and I would like to display them in a table not as plain text but as a hyperlinks. The csv file also contains photo links so I want it to directly display the images in the website. Is this possible?

I have succeeded in displaying all the content I want in a table using the code below.

[image: This is what I have at the moment.]

```
function init_table(options) {

  options = options || {};
  var csv_path = options.csv_path || "";
  var el = options.element || "table-container";
  var allow_download = options.allow_download || false;
  var csv_options = options.csv_options || {};
  var datatables_options = options.datatables_options || {};

  $("#" + el).html("<table class='table table-striped table-condensed' id='my-table'></table>");

  $.when($.get(csv_path)).then(
    function(data){

      data = data.replace(/[\r|\r\n]/g, "\n");

      var csv_data = $.csv.toArrays(data, csv_options);

      var table_head = "<thead><tr>";

      for (head_id = 0; head_id < csv_data[0].length; head_id+=2) { 
        table_head += "<th>" + csv_data[0][head_id] + "</th>";
      }

      table_head += "</tr></thead>";
      $('#my-table').append(table_head);
      $('#my-table').append("<tbody></tbody>");

      for (row_id = 1; row_id < csv_data.length; row_id++) { 
        var row_html = "<tr>";

          for (col_id = 0; col_id < csv_data[row_id].length; col_id+=2) {
              switch (col_id) {
                // img
                case 1:
                  row_html += '<td><img src="' + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + '" /></td>';
                  break;
                // link
                case 3:
                  row_html += '<td><a href="' + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + '">' + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + '</a></td>';
                  break;
                default:
                  row_html += "<td>" + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + "</td>";
              }
          }
        row_html += "</tr>";
        $('#my-table tbody').append(row_html);
      }

      $("#my-table").DataTable(datatables_options);

      if (allow_download)
        $("#" + el).append("<p><a class='btn btn-info' href='" + csv_path + "'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-download'></i> Download as CSV</a></p>");
    });
}
```

Can someone please help me on what to do? 
I really need to display all the pictures in the website, and make the links clickable.

I know this requires changing the code a lot, but I can't figure out how else to start what I am trying to create..

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I guess that instead of just wrapping each field content in a td element with `row_html += "<td>" + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + "</td>";` you have to wrap it in either a [img element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) for embedding as image or a [link element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp), depending on the value of col_id.

Comment: @ValentinHuber Thank you for helping! 
I have tried `row_html += "<td><a href=' " + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + " ' </a></td>";` but this doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may help you...

```
// process columns
for (col_id = 0; col_id < csv_data[row_id].length; col_id++) {
    switch (col_id) {
      // img
      case 1:
        row_html += '<td><img src="' + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + '" /></td>';
        break;

      // link
      case 3:
        row_html += '<td><a href="' + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + '">' + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + '</a></td>';
        break;

      default:
        row_html += "<td>" + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + "</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it. 
However, I don't know what is wrong but, this doesn't do anything to my website :(.. I don't know what is missing..

Comment: doesn't change anything? let me ask, are you wanting to print all the columns or just the image and link? can you share an image of the output?

Comment: The thing is the output is completely the same as the picture that is already posted... Maybe there is something wrong with the way I changed my code? - I have updated my code in the question so you can see how I changed it.

Comment: I want to print everything, including the prices, the titles, the photos and the links :/

Comment: just curious why in the column loop, you use `col_id+=2` instead of `col_id++`. As for updating the code, does the page cache? Try Ctrl+F5 or just shove "HELLO WORLD" in there somewhere to see if it updates...

Comment: Oh. apparently the problem was with the col_id+=2 ! Thank you for noticing! I was trying to skip some of the CSV content since it repeated the links too many times. But once I changed it to col_id++, it works!!
Thank you very much!!